# PHP MYSQL - Memory - Unable to save result set in

Tags: php, mysql, memory, browser

I have a database with 150k records which doesn't sound like a lot.  The problem I have having is that when i run a search with no filers (returning all 150k records) i "get Unable to save result set in", but when i add a filter that cuts the results it half it works fine.  Also when i run it in phpmyadmin it works fine.

It only gets this error when i run the sql in the browser.  After googling, I found that it may be something with memory in the browser not being able to return that many results.

Can someone explain this to me and more importantly provide me with a solution so that i can return all 150k records without error.

Thank you.

Comment: "Unable to save result set in" sounds like an incomplete error message. What is the entire error message?

Comment: why do you what to output 150K records to the browser ?????

Comment: There is no sense to return 150k records ;) build a paging or a search function.

Comment: Memory in the browser is not an issue until enough data has been received, which in your case doesn't sound like is happening. Still, showing that many records is a bad idea under almost every circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

use an unbuffered query when result sets may be large enough to cause memory exhaustion 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

Answer (score 0):

You should try to increment the memory limit for your PHP script.

Try putting:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

at the beginning of your script.

See also:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a broken MySQL table may cause this warning. If you think enough memory to handle your result set, simply check your table.

Comment: I can confirm that a broken table is triggering this issue, if you are looking for a fix just look into mysql errors first, if it is something with the table there will be a message "Table xyz is marked as crashed and should be repaired"